# Difficulty in making website mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, frontend

I'm having some difficultly making this site (phil-ga-surge.sh) mobile responsive. Since its just a landing page, I'm not trying to make it too complex so just wanted everything to just fall in place when the screen size is changed. I'm sure this is something simple, but for the life of me I can't figure this out. I'm drawing all blanks. This is what I have so far:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bgimg {
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dod6u4bjy/image/upload/v1536798847/water_kingdom_background.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.topleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 16px;
}

.header {
  color: white;
}

.heading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

#h3 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation: flash linear 4s infinite;
  animation: flash linear 4s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
  0% {
    opacity: 4;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 4;
  }
}
@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    opacity: 4;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 4;
  }
}

a:hover {
  color: darkgrey;
}


.logo {
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 100px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkblue;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav {
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .header {
    width: 100%;
  }
body, html {
  width: 100%;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bgimg">
    <div class="topleft">

      <nav class="nav">
        <li> <a href="https://raijinstudiosabout.carrd.co">Raijin Studios</li></a>
        <li><a href="https://thewaterkingbook.carrd.co">About the Book</li></a>

      </nav>

    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      <h1 class="header">Announcing:<br> The Water King</h1>

      <hr>
      <h3 id="h3"></h3>
    </div>

  </div>

  <footer>©Raijin Studios</footer>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have an unclosed `link` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"
```

Change it to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: No problem! Did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: @P.Murtagh When you say someone fixed your problem, it is good to accept their answer, as you'd be giving back to the community as well.

Comment: You're right, thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Everything work as soon I replace `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"` by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />`